# How to remove the folders from the stream in perforce using p4v?

Tags: perforce

> How can we remove an empty folder from stream in perforce (p4v)?

Comment: This may be better for [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/perforce), as I don't think it is a programming issue.

Answer (score 0):

A stream can't contain an empty folder, nor can any other depot path.

You should provide a little more information on what it is you're seeing, but empty folders have actually been a Perforce feature request for nearly two decades and as far as I know have yet to be implemented.  :)